# "from A to B" or "to B from A"

Tags: expressions, writing-style, phrase-usage, prepositional-phrases

Which expression is more customary? Are their situations where one would be favored over the other?

Edit:

Sorry for making the question unclear. My motivation for this question came from reading economics and finance related articles online.

As an example, there seem to be two ways of expression:

> The S&P 500 Index has risen slightly to the 2700s from the 2400s a year ago.
>
> The S&P 500 Index has risen from the 2400s a year ago to the 2700s.

My examples are not good, but I hope they illustrate my idea.

Of course, discussions on such a difference in style of expression can be extended more generally.

Comment: Letter [to the queen of England, from the high imperial commissioner Lin, and his colleagues, 1839](http://www.fas.nus.edu.sg/hist/eia/documents_archive/linzexu.php)

Comment: It's a question of emphasis -- do you want to emphasize the "from" value or the "to" value?

Answer (score 1):

According to [Google Books Ngram Viewer](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=from%20a%20to%20b%2C%20from%20b%20to%20a&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cfrom%20a%20to%20b%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cfrom%20b%20to%20a%3B%2Cc0), both expressions are used, but **from A to B** is more common.

You can talk about going between two different places (or from one idea to another)—and then going back again. But when you talk about the "forward" direction, it's more common to start with A and work down the alphabet.

For instance:

> We went from A to B, then from B to C, returned to B, and finally went back from B to A.

Although you *could* start by saying that you went **from B to A**, it's not an intuitive progression.

However, you could use it specifically if you wanted to call out something unusual:

> Rather than doing things in the proper order, I instead went from B to A.

---

It's similar to naturally saying **here and there** instead of **there and here**, or saying **this and that** instead of **that and this**.

---

**Update**: Thanks to a comment, I was actually addressing the wrong specific question.

Somehow, I had misread ***to*** **B** ***from*** **A** as ***from*** **B** ***to*** **A**.

My answer about "direction" still holds true, however. It's much more common to put the first letter in the alphabet first.

Interestingly, another Google Books Ngram Viewer [query](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=from%20a%20to%20b%2C%20to%20b%20from%20a&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cfrom%20a%20to%20b%3B%2Cc0) doesn't produce enough hits for **to B from A** to register at all.

Changing tack, Google Scholar [shows](https://scholar.google.ca/scholar?hl=en&as_sdt=0%2C5&q=%22from%20a%20to%20b%22&btnG=) 562,000 hits for **from A to B** and [shows](https://scholar.google.ca/scholar?hl=en&as_sdt=0%2C5&q=%22to%20b%20from%20a%22&btnG=) only 1,120 hits for **to B from A**.

Further, of those 1,120 hits, only a small percentage are legitimate hits—the others being false positives such as "*sends 100 packets to B. From a load*" and "*transmission to B from a given one*."

What this means is that **to B from A** is even *less* common than **from B to A**.

---

It's been suggested that **A** and **B** are meant to be taken metaphorically rather than literally. If so, then the question should be edited to clarify.

However, the same type of analysis applies. The use of **from / to** is [more common](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=from%20here%20to%20there%2C%20to%20there%20from%20here%2C%20from%20me%20to%20you%2C%20to%20me%20from%20you%2C%20from%20one%20to%20two%2C%20to%20one%20from%20two&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cfrom%20here%20to%20there%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cto%20there%20from%20here%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cfrom%20me%20to%20you%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cto%20me%20from%20you%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cfrom%20one%20to%20two%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cto%20one%20from%20two%3B%2Cc0) than **to / from**.

Comment: I think you may have asked Google Books Ngram Viewer the wrong question. The alternative is “to B from A” not “from B to A” and I suspect the question has A and B as placeholders for actual people or places. Try [this](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=from+me+to+you%2Cto+you+from+me%2Cfrom+you+to+me%2Cto+me+from+you&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cfrom%20me%20to%20you%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cto%20you%20from%20me%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cfrom%20you%20to%20me%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cto%20me%20from%20you%3B%2Cc0)

Comment: @Henry Thank you for pointing that out! I have updated my answer accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

The common expression is "from A to B," not "to B from A."  But I'm not sure that's what you're asking.  I'm not sure if you actually mean "A" and "B" or if you are using "A" and "B" as stand-ins.  If the latter, then both ways are acceptable, albeit with slightly different effect.

Examples:

- I went from my mom's house to the store.

The above sentence emphasizes the journey itself.

- I went to the store from my mom's house.

The above sentence emphasizes where I left from rather than the journey.  I'm clarifying that I went there from my mom's house, not from somewhere else.

Answer (score 0):

From A to Z is the normal phrase, since that encases the English alphabet. I have personally never heard it the other way around.

Comment: Going from A to B is a perfectly normal English phrase, simply meaning to go from one place to another (literally or figuratively).

Comment: I don't know that I've specifically heard "from A to B" but certainly "from point A to point B" is a common phrase.

Comment: True. It depends on what the phrase is meant to represent.

Answer (score 0):

While not common in everyday conversation, this particular usage ("to B from A") is often used in journalism, especially where changes in numbers are concerned. In a news story, the "to" figure is often put first to clarify that this is the current state. The "from" figure is put after that to show the rate of increase/decrease over time.

In conversational use, I would stick with "from A to B." In the specific context of describing a rate of increase or decrease, "to B from A" is allowable, particularly in news stories or reports. Which you use may depend on which you want to emphasize -- the current state of things (the "to" figure), or the more overall view (the range from A to B).